# Как заставить selenium выбрать одну из кнопок с одинаковыми атрибутами?

Tags: python, html, selenium

На сайте где я пытаюсь провести тесты есть 2 кнопки, которые ведут на одну и ту же страницу, но мне нужно проверить именно определённую кнопку (чтобы она вела на ту же страницу). Однако т.к. `selenium` выбирает первую попавшуюся по шаблону кнопку, выбирается та, что на втором скрине, а мне нужна та, что на первом скрине. Какой для этого нужно использовать шаблон?

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Chrome()


@pytest.fixture
def browser():
    global driver
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

def test_scenario_1(browser):
    # Шаг 1: Переход на https://sbis.ru/ в раздел "Контакты"
    browser.get("https://sbis.ru/")
    contacts_link = browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Контакты").click()

    # Шаг 2: Поиск баннера Тензор и клик по нему
    tensor_banner = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sbisru-Contacts__logo-tensor").click()
    windows = browser.window_handles
    browser.switch_to.window(windows[1])

    # Шаг 3: Переход на https://tensor.ru/
    assert browser.current_url == "https://tensor.ru/", "Страница tensor.ru не загрузилась"

    browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    # Шаг 4: Проверка наличия блока "Сила в людях"
    block_title = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "tensor_ru-Index__block4-bg")
    assert block_title.is_displayed(), "Блок 'Сила в людях' отсутствует"

    # Шаг 5: Переход в блоке "Подробнее" и проверка открытия https://tensor.ru/about
    podrobnee_link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[href="/about"]').click()
    assert browser.current_url == "https://tensor.ru/about", "tensor.ru/about не загрузился"
    sleep(5)
```

[image: Кнопка которая мне нужна]
[image: Кнопка которая мне не нужна, но которая выбирается]

Comment: Получайте конкретную кнопку через XPath, как вариант (есть очень удобные расширения для браузера)

Comment: какие например расширения?

Comment: xPath Finder, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что надо проскроллить вниз до элемента, пока он не будет виден.